# JWT auth with cookies - how to deal with expired token?

Tags: cookies, .net-core, jwt

Using DotNet Core 2.2, I'm using JWT auth in my app, while storing the token in cookies. All is fine apart from when the token expires.

I have the following options for my authentication in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                    options.Cookie.Name = "access_token";
                    options.TicketDataFormat = new SimpleTokenProvider.CustomJwtDataFormat(
                        SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256,
                        tokenValidationParameters);
                    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                });
```

And here is my `SimpleTokenProvider.cs` file:

```
public AuthenticationTicket Unprotect(string protectedText, string purpose)
            {
                var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                ClaimsPrincipal principal = null;
                SecurityToken validToken = null;

                try
                {
                    principal = handler.ValidateToken(protectedText, this.validationParameters, out validToken);

                    var validJwt = validToken as JwtSecurityToken;

                    if (validJwt == null)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid JWT");
                    }

                    if (!validJwt.Header.Alg.Equals(algorithm, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException($"Algorithm must be '{algorithm}'");
                    }
                }
                catch (SecurityTokenValidationException e)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                catch (ArgumentException e)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                return new AuthenticationTicket(principal, new AuthenticationProperties(), "Cookie");
            }
```

My problem is the line `handler.ValidateToken(protectedText, this.validationParameters, out validToken)` keeps throwing a timeout exception:

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenExpiredException:
>   'IDX10223: Lifetime validation failed. The token is expired. ValidTo:
>   '[PII is hidden]', Current time: '[PII is hidden]'.'

What I'd like to do in this instance is automatically generate a new token, or delete the current auth cookie.

How can I do this/what is the best way to go?

Comment: Please read about "refresh" tokens.  They are one way to handle this situation.  However, there are some cases where upon hitting an expired JWT you just have to redirect to login.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm aware of refresh tokens. My problem is how do I deal with the expired token in my `SimpleTokenProvider.cs` class?

Comment: Setting the following flag is hugely helpful in debugging situations like this. It will repleace the [PII is Hidden] with the actual error. Just remember to remove the flag before releasing to production: IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true